# Jquery Mathematics

Tags: jquery, math, if-statement

I am having trouble with a mathematical issue. With the if statement I am not sure if that is the correct way to write this? It is not working so I assume it is not. How do I write the if statement to work with my code?

```
var count = $("#hugewidth li").length;

if($( '#hugewidth' ).css("margin-left") < '-1280*(count-1)'){   

     $('#hugewidth').animate({'margin-left' : '0'});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   function animateMargin() {
     var count = $("#hugewidth li").length;
     var num = Number($( 'ul' ).css("margin-left").replace(/px|pt|cm|em/g,"")); 
     if (num < 1200 * (count-1)) {   
       return $("#hugewidth").animate({marginLeft : '0px'}, 3000);
     };
   };
   animateMargin();
```

At the original post `-1200 * (count-1)`, where `count` is a prospective positive number, for example `5`, the result would be `-1200 * (5-1)`, or `-4800`. In such an instance, if `num`, or the css `margin-left` property is any positive "number", the result would prospectively *not* be `<`, or `less than` `-4800`. Following, the `if` statement evaluation would return `false` and the `.animate()` function would not be called.

Additionally, no `duration` was set for the `.animate()` function. In the example above, the css `margin-left` property's `px` (or other valid value that may be present) was removed and the value was `cast` as a `Number`, the `-` (mathematical negative symbol or sign) was removed from the `if` statement, and a duration of `3000` was set for the `.animate()` function.

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/7S9j7/

Edit (updated)

> I'd just like the li's to slide to the next after 2 seconds however,
>   once the final li has shown i'd like it to slide back to the first li
>   element. –  Jacob Read

Took a quick glance at http://www.read.ventures/ source (html, css, js).

1) html (existing)

```
<div id="hugewidth">
  <li class="wrap100 page" style="background: url('welcomeimage.png');"></li>
  <li class="wrap100 page" style="background: url('welcomeimage.png');"></li>
  <li class="wrap100 page" style="background: black; height: 340px;"></li>
</div>
```

It appears that the `<li>` elements within `#hugewidh` are not within a `<ul>` element. Try this (html)

```
<div id="hugewidth">
  <ul>
  <li class="wrap100 page" style="background: url('welcomeimage.png');"></li>
  <li class="wrap100 page" style="background: url('welcomeimage.png');"></li>
  <li class="wrap100 page" style="background: black; height: 340px;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

2) css (existing)

```
.wrap100 {
position: relative;
float: left; /* not certain if `float` property is required */
vertical-align: top;
overflow: hidden;
width: 1280px; /* `width` set to `1280px`, `animate` `marginLeft` to `-1300px` */
}
```

3) js (existing)

Not certain about the requirement or operation of `$(window).bind()` function, or `width` variable. Additionally, not certain about the effect of the `click` functions? Not addressed here. Perhaps appropriate for a separate question? Omitted from tests with `main.js` to achieve the requirement of the present question, and most recent comment (above).

```
    $(window).bind('resize',function(){
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    });
    var width = $(window).width();
    var hugewidth =                         
    $( "#slidernavi ul li:nth-child(1)" ).click(function() {
    $('#hugewidth').animate({'margin-left' : 0});
    $(this).css('background', '#62B3EB').siblings().css('background', '#B6B6B6');
    });
    $( "#slidernavi ul li:nth-child(2)" ).click(function() {
    $('#hugewidth').animate({'margin-left' : -1280});
    $(this).css('background', '#62B3EB').siblings().css('background', '#B6B6B6');
    });
    $( "#slidernavi ul li:nth-child(3)" ).click(function() {
    $('#hugewidth').animate({'margin-left' : -1280*2});
    $(this).css('background', '#62B3EB').siblings().css('background', '#B6B6B6');
    });
```

js (addressing comment clarifying the requirement of the effect)

Try this at `main.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
function animateMargin(elem) {
  var elem = $("#hugewidth ul li").eq(0);
  $(elem).siblings().hide(0);
  return $(elem).fadeIn(1000).animate({marginLeft : '-1300px'}, 2000, function() {
    $(elem).css("marginLeft", "0px").appendTo("#hugewidth ul") && animateMargin()
  });
};animateMargin();   
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/CU3UB/

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I've applied your code to my site @ http://www.read.ventures/ however, it still does not seem to be working.

Comment: @JacobRead Please post url. Thanks.

Comment: @JacobRead  It appears that other portions may be present surrounding the above piece. Please decribe the overall effect that would prospectively would meet the requirement? Thanks

Comment: I'd just like the li's to slide to the next after 2 seconds however, once the final li has shown i'd like it to slide back to the first li element.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... with all due respect, `'-1280*(count-1)'` is a string. Remove the quotes if you want a mathematical expression.

Comment: Although I've changed this it still does not work. You can see my site live here. http://www.read.ventures

Comment: The `.css` function returns a string with a unit such as `px` appended - you have to remove that before you can do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($( '#hugewidth' ).css("margin-left") < -1280*(count-1)){   
     $('#hugewidth').animate({'margin-left' : '0'});
}
```